# Convert array in JSON file to string

Tags: javascript, json

Here's a snippet of my JSON object (EDITED) -

```
[{
    "traditional": "%",
    "simplified": "%",
    "referencedTraditional": [],
    "referencedSimplified": [],
    "pinyinNumeric": "pa1",
    "pinyinDiacritic": "pā",
    "definitions": [
        "percent (Tw)"
    ],
    "definitionsDiacritic": [
        "percent (Tw)"
    ]
},
{
"traditional":"龠","simplified":"龠","referencedTraditional":[{"cp":"9fa0","c":"龠"}],"referencedSimplified":[{"cp":"9fa0","c":"龠"}],"pinyinNumeric":"yue4","pinyinDiacritic":"yuè","definitions":["ancient unit of volume (half a 合[ge3], equivalent to 50ml)","ancient flute"],"definitionsDiacritic":["ancient unit of volume (half a 合[gě], equivalent to 50ml)","ancient flute"]},
    {"traditional":"龡","simplified":"龡","referencedTraditional":[{"cp":"9fa1","c":"龡"}],"referencedSimplified":[{"cp":"9fa1","c":"龡"}],"pinyinNumeric":"chui4","pinyinDiacritic":"chuì","definitions":["to blow (a flute)","archaic version of 吹"],"definitionsDiacritic":["to blow (a flute)","archaic version of 吹"]},
]
```

I want to convert every key called definitions from an array into a string.

E.g. From `["percent (Tw)"]` to `"percent (Tw)"`. Basically, I don't want the array brackets.

So far, I've tried looping through the file and converting every "definitions" key with `JSON.stringify()` or `toString()` -

```
translations.forEach(key => JSON.stringify((key.definitions)))
```

However, nothing changes in the outputted file.

Comment: `translations.forEach(key => JSON.stringify((key.definitions)))` ... doesn't change anything ... returning a value in forEach callback does nothing ... perhaps `translations.forEach(key => translations[key] = JSON.stringify((key.definitions)))`

Comment: What you wanna do if there is an empty array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with the code is the one below

```
translations.forEach(key => JSON.stringify((key.definitions)))
```

Simply running this statement will not update the value for the key inside that object. You have to update the object for this.

**Logic.**

- Loop through the keys in the object `translations`. I used `Object.entries(translations).forEach` for that.
- Check each key, whether it includes `"definitions"` in that key.
- If the key has `"definitions"` in that, run your stringification logic. I prefer `Array.join()` compared to `JSON.stringify`.
- Update the key of that object.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const translations = {
    "traditional": "%",
    "simplified": "%",
    "referencedTraditional": [],
    "referencedSimplified": [],
    "pinyinNumeric": "pa1",
    "pinyinDiacritic": "pā",
    "definitions": [
        "percent (Tw)"
    ],
    "definitionsDiacritic": [
        "percent (Tw)"
    ]
}
Object.entries(translations).forEach(([key, value]) => key.includes('definitions') ? translations[key] = translations[key].join("") : null);
console.log(translations);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
    traditional: '%',
    simplified: '%',
    referencedTraditional: [],
    referencedSimplified: [],
    pinyinNumeric: 'pa1',
    pinyinDiacritic: 'pā',
    definitions: ['percent (Tw)'],
    definitionsDiacritic: ['percent (Tw)'],
};

const returnStringDefinitions = (obj) => {
    const arr = [];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (key === 'definitions') arr.push(value.toString());
    }
    return arr;
};

console.log(returnStringDefinitions(obj));
```

Comment: Correction - The data should be wrapped in an array of objects ordinarily. Sorry for this. I've made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think what may be happening for you is that you aren't saving the resulting array anywhere. The approach could be to create a new object.

```
const obj = {
    traditional: '%',
    simplified: '%',
    referencedTraditional: [],
    referencedSimplified: [],
    pinyinNumeric: 'pa1',
    pinyinDiacritic: 'pā',
    definitions: ['percent (Tw)'],
    definitionsDiacritic: ['percent (Tw)'],
};

const output = Object.keys(obj).reduce((accumulator, currentKey) => {
    const currentValue = obj[currentKey];
    if (currentKey === 'definitions' && Array.isArray(currentValue)) {
            accumulator[currentKey] = currentValue.join(''); 
    } else {
        accumulator[currentKey] = currentValue;
    }
    return accumulator;
}, {})

console.log(output);
```

This solution checks if it is an array, and also just joins everything in the array just in case there are multiple things in the array, but how this is handled is really up to you :)